# Leave Event / Regex Implemented (Query about ignoring Textboxes if empty / null)

Tags: c#, events

I'm new to C#, and finding some difficulties when trying to implement the 'ignore regex function when textbox is empty'.

As shown below, within Leave event I have made it so that the data submitted in the name textbox is of alphabetic characters, however, upon testing, the application still warns me that the textbox requires alphabetic characters even if the textbox is EMPTY / NULL.

What I would like is to maintain the same regex function, but I want the application to NOT warn me about the requirements if textboxes are left empty.

Many thanks in advance.

```
    private void txtName_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(this.txtName.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters.", "Warning");

            this.txtName.ResetText();
        }
        else if (txtName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to use is ^[a-zA-Z]*$

- ^ Beginning of string
- [a-zA-Z]* with the addition of the * it represents 0+ Alpha
  characters
- $ end of string

Comment: While this is a good answer, you should also explain why this regex works for OP (full match, 0-many)

Comment: Works perfect - Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: One more thing if that is not a problem - I want my Regex (using "^[a-zA-Z ]*$") to accept also the apostrophe character, as I will be using this for Address textbox. Is there a way to implement that, please?

Comment: @avner1169 ^[a-zA-Z']*$